# Dell D520 getting hot | 12.10

Tags: 12.04, dell

I know the my laptop is quite hot when it was in win7, but after I changed OS (ubuntu 12.04), I notice that it gets even hotter.

I also notice that when it gets hotter, it's starting to act slow :( .. Do the laptop temperature has something to do why it's getting slow like I mention? But I'm only running few applications like chrome, terminal and an editor.

CURRENT

I've tried to upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu which is 12.10 to see if things may change. Unfortunately, it did not. My laptop still goes super hot and I'm hearing the fan always spinning fast.

@ttoine - as per your suggestion I tried to install the cpu frequency indicator, and I'm currently using the Powersave option. It didn't help I think. Looking at sensors, the temperature of my laptop is playing between 60-70+

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +63.5°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +63.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +63.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

----

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +70.5°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +70.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU may be on performance mode only.

1. Check if you can fix that in the Bios, enabling change of frequencies depending on cpu use (scaling). The way you can do it depends on your bios. On laptops, it is already enabled: most of the time, it allows to save battery power.
2. You can install "indicator-cpufreq", restart your computer. A new icon should be available near the date, click on it and choose "On demand".

`sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq`

"On demand" means that if you don't use your CPU, the system will scale it at the lower power available (computing and energy). If you run intensive applications, the system will set the CPU to the required power needed. You can set it to "Performance" so it will stay at full power, etc.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm not exactly sure how to do that #1, nor capable of doing it.. could you give me more hints about it?
as of #2, i already installed the said package, and after I restarted my laptop, yes it appear and the option is already selected as 'Ondemand'. What does it mean?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the content of my last comment.