# Laptop Heating Lenovo Z570

Tags: power-management

I have just started using Ubuntu. Loving the way it works but I am having issue with heating.

It is being heating more than it did when I had Windows 7 installed. Not sure if its problem of drivers as I have installed Drivers when it promoted for my Nvidia graphics card.

I have two graphics card, Intel HD 3000 and Nvidia one. Please help me with this. I think due to this heating issue I am also getting low battery backup. The battery drains much faster.

Lenovo Z570
12.04 LTS

Comment: Suggest you visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/267815/dell-d520-getting-hot-12-10 and see if your machine is stuck in 'performance mode' only.

Comment: Have you got bumblebee installed? I have a G570 or something similar I think and when I use the nvidia card it heats up a lot more than without it.

Answer (score 1):

Sucks, huh?  I bought a laptop cooler.  Actually, I went through a few of them (don't go cheap!!!!) until I found one that has, along with the obvious fans, little feet on the bottom that flip out about an inch.  When sitting on a desk, this feature elevates the computer and the cooler so air can circulate ***beneath*** the laptop cooler.  This little aspect is VERY important

My fan spins up whenever I play WOW or watch Netflix.  This last cooler is a miracle worker.  I don't have it just now, because I'm not at home, but I think it was from the Cooler Master brand.

Answer (score 1):

For hybrid systems I recommend to update to Ubuntu 13.10 as it is the first release to fully support hybrid systems like yours.

For your overheating problem (uninstall all previous drivers you have):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime
```

Then go to nvidia drivers setting page and set intel gpu for normal use. Prime is a package for hybrid systems like yours.

To extend the battery life greatly do the following:

TLP helps laptop reduce the ammount of power consumed in a much more efficient way than any other:

First: Uninstall laptop mode tools

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Then install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Finally start it:

```
sudo tlp start
```